# ng build error - Property does not exist

Tags: angular

when i run `ng build --prod`, i get the following error:

```
ERROR in src\app\user-item.component.html<4,26>: :Property 'displayName does not exist on type 'User.'
```

This error does not appear otherwise. I'd really appreciate some guidance on how i can resolve this.

the foll is my user-list component with a child component user-item

```
<div class="userList">
  <app-user-item
  [user]=user *ngFor="let user of users">
  </app-user-item>
</div>
```

I have an input property user on UserItemComponent:

```
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user: User;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the foll is my html of UserItemComponent:

```
<div class="userItem">
  <span class="status" [ngClass]=(user.status)>
  </span>
  <span class="userName">
    {{user.displayName}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your  class/Interface **`User`** has a property named **`displayName`**

```
export class User {
    uid?: string;
    email?: string;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    displayName?: string;
    status?: string;
}
```

Comment: i have added displayName property `export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() user: User;
  displayName: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}` but im still getting the same error on ng build... i dont get any of this error when im serving the application on localhost

Comment: you need to add inside the user class not as a separate

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't understand... what do you mean inside the user class

Comment: where do you import the User from ?

Comment: i have a user class: `export class User {
    uid?: string;
    email?: string;
    username?: string;
    password?: string;
    status?: string;
}`

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan... the problem that i am facing now is that the build process is getting stuck at 92%...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160876/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-nosail).

Comment: hey it took a lot of time... but it finally created the dist folder... thanks v much for your help..